# Creating Custom Content Element in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

Cany anybody tell me how to render the following structure in 
typo3 without developing a new extension.

```
<div class="sidebar-details">
    <div class="sidebar-details-title">
        <h4><span>MY TITLE</span></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-details-body">
        <p>
              TEXT
            </p>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be the best/recommended way to achieve this ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your use-case. Is this an element that will be all around your page, just like "Text" or "Text with images"?

Comment: Yes i would like to have this as a reusable element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using gridelements.
Gives you exactly what you want.
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gridelements

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the RTE html mode and put it in its source or make use of HTML element, but that's depending on your needs.

If you want to keep RTE functions for editing the text what I mentioned first is the recommended way. Have done it several times myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Template mapping using Templavoila so, you can create FCE(Flexible content element) for it and you can map this part.

If you are using fluid template mapping so, you can create gridelement for it. and map all part.